# Delete uncessary references from my csproj, a automatic way?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008

Existe a possibility to remove or identify all my references in my csproj is not used, if yes its cool for create a most speed and more easy to deploy software? anyone have ideias?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142627/tools-for-finding-unused-references

Answer (score 1):

3 ways to solve this:

1. Easy, but slow and uncool - remove the reference and build, then count the losses (meaning, the error messages);
2. Little harder, but faster and automatic - write a program which parses your project file and for each reference, removes it and runs MSBuild automatically using Shell and counts the errors;
3. Hard, but fancy, very fast and automatic - write a program which parses your project file and for each reference:

   b) finds the referenced assembly,

   c) loads it into memory,

   d) lists all of the namespaces and types,

   e) does a global search in your project to determine if any type is used in your project.

Your choice. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a reasonably good Visual Studio extension for this:

- [Visual Studio 2010 Reference
  Assistant](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fc504cc6-5808-4da8-ae86-8d3f9ed81606)
- [Visual Studio 2012 Reference
  Assistant](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ff717422-f6a7-4f18-b972-f7540eaf371e)

Right-click on references and 'Remove Unused References'. As the reviews mention, it sometimes seems to remove too much. Maybe they will improve it.

Comment: Thanks but i founded it a year ago ;)